# Data In Long and Wide Format, Need to Convert to Just Long in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr, reshape2

I'm working with a dataset which is in both and wide format. It looks like:

```
ID week1 week2 week3 ... week12  
1   2     NA     NA  ...  NA  
1   NA    3      NA  ...  NA
1   NA    NA     3   ...  NA
...
1   NA    NA     NA  ...  4
2   4     NA     NA  ...  NA
2   NA    5      NA  ...  NA
2   NA    NA     3   ...  NA
```

I'm struggling to now convert this into solely long format for analysis. I'm looking to get it set up like:

```
ID week value
1   1    2
1   2    3
1   3    3
...
1   12   4
2   1    4
2   2    5
2   3    3
```

Can anyone give any suggestions for doing this in R please? I've tried reshape2 and dplyr/tidyr but I keep ending up with too many observations when I select the ID variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
library(dplyr)

# small data sample
df <- read.table(text = 'ID week1 week2 week3 week4  
1   2     NA     NA    NA  
1   NA    3      NA    NA
1   NA    NA     3     NA
1   NA    NA     NA    4
2   4     NA     NA    NA
2   NA    5      NA    NA
2   NA    NA     3     NA', header = T)

df %>% 
   data.table::melt(id.vars = 'ID') %>% 
   na.omit()
```

Answer (score 0):

**1) gather** Using `wide` shown reproducibly in the Note 1 at the end, use `gather` to convert `wide` to long form, drop the NA rows and the sort.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

wide %>%
  gather("week", "value", -ID) %>%
  drop_na %>%
  arrange(ID, week)
```

giving:

```
  ID  week value
1  1 week1     2
2  1 week2     3
3  1 week3     3
4  1 week4     4
5  2 week1     4
6  2 week2     5
7  2 week3     3
```

**2) reshape**  Using only base R:

```
varying <- list(value = 2:5)
long <- na.omit(reshape(wide, dir = "long", timevar = "week", 
  varying = varying, v.names = names(varying)))[1:3]
long[order(long$ID, long$week), ]
```

giving:

```
    ID week value
1.1  1    1     2
2.2  1    2     3
3.3  1    3     3
4.4  1    4     4
5.1  2    1     4
6.2  2    2     5
7.3  2    3     3
```

**3) data.table**  Using `varying` from (2) we can use `melt` from data.table.  Note that we could either specify the id.vars or the measure.vars but in the comments it was stated that we might want to be generalize this to multiple variables and the measure.vars approach generalizes.

```
library(data.table)
longDT <- na.omit(melt(as.data.table(wide), measure.vars = varying, 
  variable.name = "week"))
setkey(longDT, ID, week)
longDT
```

giving:

```
   ID  week value
1:  1 week1     2
2:  1 week2     3
3:  1 week3     3
4:  1 week4     4
5:  2 week1     4
6:  2 week2     5
7:  2 week3     3
```

### Note 1

The input used in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "
ID week1 week2 week3 week4
1   2     NA     NA   NA  
1   NA    3      NA   NA
1   NA    NA     3    NA
1   NA    NA     NA   4
2   4     NA     NA   NA
2   NA    5      NA   NA
2   NA    NA     3    NA"
wide <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

### Note 2

Regarding having multiple variables data.table's `melt` supports that.
Suppose we have the following:

```
Lines2 <- "
ID week1var1 week1var2 week2var1 week2var2 week3var1 week3var2 week4var1 week4var2
1 1 2 20 NA NA NA NA NA NA
2 1 NA NA 3 30 NA NA NA NA
3 1 NA NA NA NA 3 30 NA NA
4 1 NA NA NA NA NA NA 4 40
5 2 4 40 NA NA NA NA NA NA
6 2 NA NA 5 50 NA NA NA NA
7 2 NA NA NA NA 3 30 NA NA"
wide2 <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)

library(data.table)

varying2 <- split(names(wide2)[-1], 
  sub("(.*\\d)(\\D.*)", "\\2", names(wide2)[-1]))

longDT2 <- na.omit(melt(as.data.table(wide2), measure.vars = varying2, 
  variable.name = "week"))
setkey(longDT2, ID, week)
longDT2
```

giving:

```
   ID week var1 var2
1:  1    1    2   20
2:  1    2    3   30
3:  1    3    3   30
4:  1    4    4   40
5:  2    1    4   40
6:  2    2    5   50
7:  2    3    3   30
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! Is there any way to take it a step further to include multiple variables, so something like:

ID week1var1 week1var2 week1var3 week2var1 week2var2 week2var3 to

ID week var1 var2 var3